Old kernel after upgrading from 22.04 to 24.04
I fell into a known bug (gnome-shell failure https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/2055012) during the upgrade from Ubuntu 22.04 to 24.04.
I had to go to recovery mode to manually handle the error. I could make it and now I have Ubuntu 24.04. But the kernel seems to remain on 6.5.0-1020-oem.
It seems kernel v 6.8 never installed if I do ll /boot/vmlinuz* I get:
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       24 Apr 21 19:08 /boot/vmlinuz -> vmlinuz-6.5.0-28-generic
-rw------- 1 root root 12646344 Mär 11 17:07 /boot/vmlinuz-6.1.0-1036-oem
-rw------- 1 root root 14237864 Mär 18 17:00 /boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-1019-oem
-rw------- 1 root root 14235624 Apr  3 12:27 /boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-1020-oem
-rw------- 1 root root 14234280 Apr  4 15:19 /boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-28-generic
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       22 Apr 21 19:08 /boot/vmlinuz.old -> vmlinuz-6.5.0-1020-oem

How can I upgrade my kernel?
I'm also using Ubuntu Pro. But I see I can't enable "Kernel Livepatch" anymore.

"It seems kernel v 6.8 never installed" That may be an indication your release-upgrade was incomplete (a.k.a. "partial" or perhaps just "failed"). Or perhaps that a previous customization must be undone.

Check that you have the linux-image-generic package installed. If not, install it.

$ apt list linux-image-generic
Listing... Done
linux-image-generic/nable,now 6.8.0-31.31 amd64 [installed,automatic]


Run sudo apt update, and check for the correct release name on each line. Fix all that are incorrect.

When 100% of the release names are correct, then run sudo apt full-upgrade



sudo  apt install linux-image-generic did it. Thanks.
